# update value at specific index in NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray

I am hoping not to need to use an NSMutableArray here. I have an array with 10 elements. I want to change the value at index 4. Is there a way to do this without having to use NSMutableArray? The problem with NSMutableArray is that we can change anything about it, including its size. I don't want the size of this array to change accidentally. I just want to change the value at index 4 from say 22 to 25. How might I do that? doing `array[4]=25` is not working.

Comment: You can't change an immutable array. So yes, you need, at least temporarily, a mutable array.

Comment: You can, of course, change the value of the **object** addressed from the array, if the object itself is mutable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NSArray *ar1 = @[@"1",@"2"];
NSMutableArray *ar1update = [ar1 mutableCopy];
ar1update[1] = @"Changed";
ar1 = [NSArray arrayWithArray:ar1update];
```

Comment: I do not think this is a good answer. It would wiser to just have NSMutableArray and deal with that extended functionality rather than making mutableCopy and rebuild the whole array again.

Comment: It was more of answering his question to the letter. Aside from that, I respectfully disagree with your statement, if the caller expects an immutable array, give it that. Don't swap it out for a mutable one and vice versa. And copies are extremely cheap since iOS 11, since Foundation uses copy on write for collections.

Comment: I agree with you, memory copying is almost lossless in terms of time. But frequent `copy` execution can easily lead to memory fragmentation which is an issue sometimes hard to detect. And swaping from `NSArray` to mutable version might have perfect sense. Author needs to change values in his array and that's what `mutable` version of array is for. But I do agree, there might be different cases and there might be one where your solution would fit perfectly.

Comment: And if author cares so much about extended functionality `NSMutableArray` provides, he can init `NSMutableArray` object and store it to `NSArray`. And whenever he needs to change the value, he can just assign it to `NSMutableArray` pointer and hence avoid any memory operations overheads.

Comment: Sorry, instead of "cares" I meant "worries"

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to create a new NSArray and change your pointer to a new NSArray.  I can give an example...

In interface:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *myArray;
```

In implementation:

```
- (void) updateMyArray{
    NSMutableArray *myArrayMut = [self.myArray mutableCopy];
    myArrayMut[4] = @"new item";
    self.myArray = [myArrayMut copy];
}
```

So basically, you can create a mutable copy temporarily, make the change you need, and then make an immutable copy.  Once you have the immutable copy, you can point myArray to the new copy.  As long as you are only changing existing items in `updateMyArray` and the myArray starts out with 10 items or less, you will never be able to have more than 10 items.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wish to use `NSMutableArray` how about a plain old C array? E.g.:

```
int array[10];
...
array[4] = 25;
```

You can store Objective-C objects in such an array and ARC will handle the memory management.

If you really want a fixed-sized `NSArray`/`NSMutableArray` you can do that by subclassing those types yourself - subclassing `NSArray` only requires implementing two methods and you can use an underlying C array or `NSMutableArray` for the actual storage.

HTH